# Phase difference removal by using Filtering, butterworth, filtfilt command

Tags: matlab, filter, signals, phase, butterworth

I am using 6th order Butterworth bandpass filter to extract the 10-20 Hz band from the signal (x). After that, I applied the filtfilt command on to the Butterworth bandpass filtered signal (10-20 Hz) to remove the phase delay. Is that I am doing right?
Thanks in advance. The code is given below. Feel free to correct the code.

```
Fs = 500;

fcutlow = 6;     % low cut frequency in Hz

fcuthigh = 14;   % high cut frequency in Hz

[b,a] = butter(6,[fcutlow,fcuthigh]/(Fs/2));


Butterworth_bandpass_filter  = filter(b,a,x);

Filt_filt_signal = filtfilt(b,a, Butterworth_bandpass_filter);
```

Comment: No the way you are doing it right now wont result in the expected result. the first filter command adds a phase delay and the second command filters the signal again but with zero phase delay. So at the end you are still having the phase delay from the first filtering (you should see it if you plot all the signals). You should just use the filtfilt as this function first filters in the forward direction and the backwards, and in this way it cancels the phase delay.

Comment: In addition to what @Irreducible said, you should [avoid the `b, a` representation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/butter.html#bucsfmj) with Butterworth filters. Also, for a _bandpass_ Butterworth filter the order is _twice_ the value specified as first input, so for order 6 order you should specify 3 as input

Comment: Thanks @Irreducible. What do you mean by "for order 6 order you should specify 3 as input" Luis Mendo. I did not get your point.